# How can I fix the error in duplicate tuples and sort correctly?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can anyone help me understand the error?
My query:

```
select s1.name, s1.grade, s2.name, s2.grade
from student s1, student s2, likes l1, likes l2
where (s1.id_student = l1.id_student1 and s2.id_student = l1.id_student2)
and (s2.id_student = l2.id_student1 and s1.id_student = l2.id_student2)
and s1.name <= s2.name
order by s1.name, s2.name;
```

**Return:**

Cassandra|9 Gabriel|9

Gabriel 11|Gabriel|9

Gabriel|9|Gabriel|11

Jessica 11|Kyle|12

**But the correct thing would be [exactly in that order]:**

Cassandra|9|Gabriel|9

Jessica|11|Kyle|12

Gabriel|9|Gabriel|11

**RS3 - For every pair of students who both like each other, return the name and grade of both students. Include each pair only once, with the two names in alphabetical order.**

```
CREATE SCHEMA socialnetworkschema;

/* Create the schema for our tables */

SET SEARCH_PATH=socialnetworkschema;


CREATE TABLE socialnetworkschema.student (

  id_student SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

  name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,

  grade int DEFAULT NULL

);


CREATE TABLE socialnetworkschema.friend (

  id_student1 int DEFAULT NULL,

  id_student2 int DEFAULT NULL,

  FOREIGN KEY (id_student1) REFERENCES socialnetworkschema.student (id_student) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,

  FOREIGN KEY (id_student2) REFERENCES socialnetworkschema.student (id_student) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

);


CREATE TABLE socialnetworkschema.likes (

  id_student1 int DEFAULT NULL,

  id_student2 int DEFAULT NULL,

  FOREIGN KEY (id_student1) REFERENCES socialnetworkschema.student (id_student) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,

  FOREIGN KEY (id_student2) REFERENCES socialnetworkschema.student (id_student) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

);



/* Populate the tables with our data */

insert into socialnetworkschema.student values (1689, 'Gabriel', 9);

insert into socialnetworkschema.student values (1510, 'Jordan', 9);

insert into socialnetworkschema.student values (1381, 'Tiffany', 9);

insert into socialnetworkschema.student values (1709, 'Cassandra', 9);

insert into socialnetworkschema.student values (1101, 'Haley', 10);

insert into socialnetworkschema.student values (1782, 'Andrew', 10);

insert into socialnetworkschema.student values (1468, 'Kris', 10);

insert into socialnetworkschema.student values (1641, 'Brittany', 10);

insert into socialnetworkschema.student values (1247, 'Alexis', 11);

insert into socialnetworkschema.student values (1316, 'Austin', 11);

insert into socialnetworkschema.student values (1911, 'Gabriel', 11);

insert into socialnetworkschema.student values (1501, 'Jessica', 11);

insert into socialnetworkschema.student values (1304, 'Jordan', 12);

insert into socialnetworkschema.student values (1025, 'John', 12);

insert into socialnetworkschema.student values (1934, 'Kyle', 12);

insert into socialnetworkschema.student values (1661, 'Logan', 12);


insert into socialnetworkschema.friend values (1510, 1381);

insert into socialnetworkschema.friend values (1510, 1689);

insert into socialnetworkschema.friend values (1689, 1709);

insert into socialnetworkschema.friend values (1381, 1247);

insert into socialnetworkschema.friend values (1709, 1247);

insert into socialnetworkschema.friend values (1689, 1782);

insert into socialnetworkschema.friend values (1782, 1468);

insert into socialnetworkschema.friend values (1782, 1316);

insert into socialnetworkschema.friend values (1782, 1304);

insert into socialnetworkschema.friend values (1468, 1101);

insert into socialnetworkschema.friend values (1468, 1641);

insert into socialnetworkschema.friend values (1101, 1641);

insert into socialnetworkschema.friend values (1247, 1911);

insert into socialnetworkschema.friend values (1247, 1501);

insert into socialnetworkschema.friend values (1911, 1501);

insert into socialnetworkschema.friend values (1501, 1934);

insert into socialnetworkschema.friend values (1316, 1934);

insert into socialnetworkschema.friend values (1934, 1304);

insert into socialnetworkschema.friend values (1304, 1661);

insert into socialnetworkschema.friend values (1661, 1025);

insert into socialnetworkschema.friend select id_student2, id_student1 from friend;


insert into socialnetworkschema.likes values(1689, 1709);

insert into socialnetworkschema.likes values(1709, 1689);

insert into socialnetworkschema.likes values(1782, 1709);

insert into socialnetworkschema.likes values(1911, 1247);

insert into socialnetworkschema.likes values(1247, 1468);

insert into socialnetworkschema.likes values(1641, 1468);

insert into socialnetworkschema.likes values(1316, 1304);

insert into socialnetworkschema.likes values(1501, 1934);

insert into socialnetworkschema.likes values(1934, 1501);

insert into socialnetworkschema.likes values(1025, 1101);

insert into socialnetworkschema.likes values(1689, 1911);

insert into socialnetworkschema.likes values(1911, 1689);
```

Comment: Just use: `s1.id_student <= s2.id_student` and that might fix it.  But you really should get into the habit of using explicit joins...had you done this, it might have been easier for you to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should consider rewriting your query to use explicit modern joins.  After this, your logic for connecting two student records needs to change a bit.

```sql
with cte as (
    select
        s1.name as name1, s1.grade as grade1, s2.name as name2, s2.grade as grade2,
        row_number() over (partition by least(s1.name, s2.name), greatest(s1.name, s2.name) order by s1.name) rn
    from student s1
    inner join likes l1
        on s1.id_student = l1.id_student1
    inner join student s2
        on l1.id_student2 = s2.id_student
    inner join likes l2
        on l2.id_student1 = s2.id_student and
           l2.id_student2 = s1.id_student
    where s1.id_student <> s2.id_student
    order by s1.name, s2.name
)

select name1, grade1, name2, grade2
from cte
where rn = 1;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Since your requirement is to find all students who *mutually* liked each other, we approach this by making a round trip to and from the `student` table.  The `likes` table is what is known as a *junction* table in SQL.  It exists to represent a one directional liked from one student to another.  We join as follows:

```
student -> likes -> student -> likes ---
   ^                                   |
   |___________________________________|
```

That is, a mutual like means that there exists a path we can find matching the above cycle.

Comment: I didn't understand this logic, because it still doesn't return the correct answer: 3 tuples

Cassandra | 9 | Gabriel | 9

Jessica | 11 | Kyle | 12

Gabriel | 9 | Gabriel | 11

Comment: @Thomas According to the expected output in your own question, in fact this output looks correct to me.  What were you expecting and why?

Comment: Only students who like each other should return.

Comment: In my query, I returned a duplicate tuple:
  Gabriel 11 | Gabriel | 9
Gabriel | 9 | Gabriel | 11

Comment: And I fail to order

Comment: Not possible, and `WHERE s1.name < s2.name` prevents this from happening.  You are not running my answer, you are using other code.

Comment: In your query appears Alexis and Chris. Alexis liked Chris, but Chris didn't like Alexis.

Comment: insert into socialnetworkschema.likes values(1247, 1468);

Comment: But it doesn't exist: insert into socialnetworkschema.likes values (1468, 1247);

Comment: `insert into socialnetworkschema.likes values(1247, 1468);` ... this definitely appears in your setup data.  Note that the direction of the like can be in either direction.

Comment: The correct thing would be to appear 3 tuples, in that order:
I)Cassandra | 9 | Gabriel | 9

II)Jessica | 11 | Kyle | 12

III)Gabriel | 9 | Gabriel | 11

Comment: Yes appears (1247, 1468); You're right. But it doesn't appear  (1468, 1247). You should only return when this occurs. That is the rule.

Comment: Alexis must have liked Chris. Chris must have liked Alexis. (1247, 1468); (1468, 1247);

Comment: @Thomas Either I didn't read the requirements, you didn't explain, or maybe both.  In any case, please check my updated answer.

Comment: I understood what you did. And I've done that too. But the problem is that Gabrel (1689) and Gabriel (1911) do not appear.The last two lines are: insert into likes values (1689, 1911); insert into likes values (1911, 1689); These students have the same names, but different id's.

Comment: Sure, then make the "duplicate" assertion using the `id_student` value instead of just the name, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you brother. Many functions that were not taught in class. But I will study them now. Thank you very much.